# Authenticate VueJS app to Django DRF back end using sessions

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

Good afternoon,

I am writing an app structured with two docker containers.  Docker1 is the front end VueJS app, Docker2 is the backend Django DRF API.  I would like to manage access using Sessions (NOT JWT's).

I am having trouble finding resources to help me get started on this approach.  Does anyone have any good resources on how to interact with authenticating and managing Django sessions over DRF?  Most of the examples use a DJango template form to do initial authentication which is not an option in this case.

EDIT: To be more specific, I intend to make the ajax calls via axios and expect to post to the built-in auth views.  My question is around how to handle the csrf_token items.

Thanks for your help.

BCBB

Comment: Anyone has answers, because I also encountered this problem? :) OP have you resolved it?